# How to change output of weekdays from Hebrew to English

Tags: r

I want to extract weekday using the `weekdays` function.

[image: what i get in the console]

But unfortunately I get my results in Hebrew.

How can I change this?

I prefer to change it to English. If this is not possible, I would prefer to convert them to numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your locale to the desired language/region.

For example changing it to English can be done with:

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "English_United States.1252")
```